# django- get all model instances with overlapping date ranges

Tags: python, django, filter

Lets say I have the following model:

```
class DateRange(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
```

Is there a way to get all pairs of DateRange instances with any overlap in their `start` to `end` range?  For example, if I had:

```
  id |  start              |  end
-----+---------------------+---------------------
   1 | 2020-01-02 12:00:00 | 2020-01-02 16:00:00  # overlap with 2, 3 and 5
   2 | 2020-01-02 13:00:00 | 2020-01-02 14:00:00  # overlap with 1 and 3
   3 | 2020-01-02 13:30:00 | 2020-01-02 17:00:00  # overlap with 1 and 2
   4 | 2020-01-02 10:00:00 | 2020-01-02 10:30:00  # no overlap
   5 | 2020-01-02 12:00:00 | 2020-01-02 12:30:00  # overlap with 1
```

I'd want:

```
 id_1 | id_2
------+-----
    1 |    2
    1 |    3
    1 |    5
    2 |    3
```

Any thoughts on the best way to do this?  The order of id_1 and id_2 doesn't matter, but I do need it to be distinct (e.g.- `id_1=1, id_2=2` is the same as `id_1=2, id_2=1` and should not be repeated)